# how can i delete repeated character in string without without considering space?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

how can i convert my string to this ?
here is the question sample :

delete("progress report template elementary school")

```
****======> progres report emplate lementary schol****
```

but I need space at the end .

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeDuplicateCharacters(string){
 return string
    .split('')
    .filter(function(item, pos, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) == pos || item == " ";
    })
    .join('');
  
}
console.log(removeDuplicateCharacters('progress report template elementary school'));
```

the output

```
"proges t mla ny ch"
```